# Let $k$ be a fixed positive integer. Prove $f(n)=gcd(n,k)$ is multiplicative.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, multiplicative-function

This is what I have to far...

Let $f(x)=g \implies gcd(x,k)=g$
We can then write, $ax+bk=g$

Let $f(y)=h \implies gcd(y,k)=h$
We can write, $cy+dk=h$

Multiplying, $(ax+bk)(cy+dk)=gh$

$\implies axcy+axdk+cybk+bdkk=gh$
$\implies acxy+k(adx+cby+bdk)=gh$

Let $r=ac$ and $s=adx+cby+bdk$

$\implies rxy+sk=gh$
Thus, $gcd(xy,k)=gh$

$\implies f(xy)=f(x) \cdot f(y)$

Hence, $f(n)=gcd(n,k)$ is multiplicative.

I was just wondering if this looked good...

Comment: Not sure I follow. with $k=2$, say, $f(4)=2\neq f(2)^2$.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Did you possibly mean to show that  $\gcd (m,n)=1\implies f(nm)=f(n)f(m)$?

Comment: @lulu That's what it means for a function to be multiplicative in number theory.

Comment: @N.S.  I understand that, but I am not persuaded that the OP does.  Nowhere in the argument is  the assumption that $\gcd (x,y)=1$ used (well, at least I can't see where it is used).

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ if we have $ax + by = c$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ we cannot conclude that $\gcd(x,y) = c$, rather we can say that $\gcd(x,y) | c$. Thus in your proof we have $\gcd(xy,k) | gh$. Clearly we have $g | \gcd(xy,k)$ and $h | \gcd(xy,k)$. Let $\gcd(g,h) = l$. Then $l | g$ and $l | h$. Since $g | x$ and $h | y$ we have $l | x$ and $l | y$ so $l | \gcd(x,y) = 1$ thus $l = 1$. Therefore $gh | \gcd(xy,k)$ and since $\gcd(xy,k) | gh$ we can now conclude that $gh = \gcd(xy,k)$ so $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$.